# How do setup Stripe payout to vendor on our marketplace

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

We are building a marketplace, what is the best setup/api to payout to our vendor setup? How does stripe do this?

Answer (score 0):

That's a very broad question but essentially you will need to read into Stripe Connect https://stripe.com/docs/connect. This enables a few different models of funds flows that will depend on your business and market place that you're building.

Some of the basic topics are how to create charges and share revenue with connected accounts, or how to creates charges on behalf of connected accounts which I am assuming would be the vendors in your market place. It's a big topic so I would suggest starting with our core connect docs.